# How to use two pipes to send messages between child/parent

Tags: c++

**using pipe to send message between parent and child**

I couldn't figure out the error on my code

Here is my code:

```
/* Using a pipe to send data from a parent to a child process
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {

    int            f_des[2];
    int            f_des2[2];

    static char    message[5];

    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "Usage: " << *argv << " message\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (pipe(f_des) == -1 || pipe(f_des2) == -1) {             // generate the pipe

        perror("Pipe");
        return 2;
    }

    switch (fork( )) {

        case -1:
            perror("Fork");
            return 3;

        case 0:                              // In the child

            close(f_des[1]);

            if (read(f_des[0], message, BUFSIZ) != -1) {
                cout << "Message received by child: [" << message
                     << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Read");
                return 4;
            }

            close(f_des[0]);
            close(f_des2[0]);

            if (write(f_des[1], argv[2], strlen(argv[2])) != -1) {
                cout << "Message sent by child   : [" <<
                        argv[1] << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Write");
                return 5;
            }

            break;

        default:                             // In the Parent

            close(f_des[0]);

            if (write(f_des[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) != -1) {
                cout << "Message sent by parent   : [" <<
                        argv[1] << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Write");
                return 6;
            }

            close(f_des[0]);
            close(f_des2[0]);

            if (read(f_des[0], message, BUFSIZ) != -1) {
                cout << "Message received by parent: [" << message
                     << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Read");
                return 7;
            }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Your code has some problematic formatting errors and needs to list a specific problem, how the code should function properly, and a verifiable outcome.

Comment: See stackoverflow.com's help center for instructions on properly formatting posted code.

Answer (score 0):

This code appears to be very confused.

The child process `close(f_des[1]);`-s, then later tries to write to it.

The parent process `close(f_des[0]);`-s. And it closes it not once, but twice. Then it tries to read from it. It's already hard enough to read from a file after you close it once; you can be assured that you have absolutely no chance of success in this endeavour, whatsoever, after closing it twice.

You probably need to sit down, and draw a diagram, on a piece of paper, of all four file descriptors, the two pairs of pipes, and what each one of them should be doing in each process, parent and child; and which one of them needs to be closed in each process.

Comment: The code it has to send message from parent to child. Display the message. Then the child send message to parent.

Comment: Sounds like a plan. Good luck with correctly implementing your code, but stackoverflow.com is not a web site where you can find someone else to write your code for you, correctly.

Comment: -Sam Varshavchik.. I tried to solve it and asked professional people on this website to look what is my mistake, I did not ask any body to write me the code. By the way, I solve it

Answer (score 0):

I tried to modify this program so the child, upon receipt of the message, changes its case and returns the message (via a pipe) to the parent, where it is then displayed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int
main(int argc, char *argv[ ]) {
    int            f_des[2];
    static char    message[5];
    if (argc != 2) {
        cerr << "Usage: " << *argv << " message\n";
        return 1;
    }
    if (pipe(f_des) == -1) {             // generate the pipe
        perror("Pipe");     return 2;
    }
    switch (fork( )) {
        case -1:
            perror("Fork");     return 3;
        case 0:                              // In the child
            close(f_des[1]);
            if (read(f_des[0], message, BUFSIZ) != -1) {
                cout << "Message received by child: [" << message
                << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Read");    return 4;
            }
            break;
        default:                             // In the Parent
            close(f_des[0]);
            if (write(f_des[1], argv[1], strlen(argv[1])) != -1) {
                cout << "Message sent by parent   : [" <<
                argv[1] << "]" << endl;
                cout.flush();
            } else {
                perror("Write");   return 5;
            }
    }
    return 0;
}
```